# numeric и money что лучше для денег?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Прочитал в документации про денежный тип - `money`. В книгах ни раз видел упоминания:

> `numeric` тип следует выбирать для хранения денежных сумм, а также в
>   других случаях, когда требуется гарантировать точность вычислений.

Comment: Money - это скалированный BIGINT. К тому же при кастинге для минимизации проблем с точностью требующий двойных преобразований... см. [Monetary Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`money` зависит от локали и потому весьма неудобен в реальном использовании - необходимо строго следить за настройками локали, а так же этот тип выводит символ валюты.

```
melkij=> show lc_monetary ;
 lc_monetary 
-------------
 ru_RU.UTF-8
(1 строка)

melkij=> create temp table moneytest (v money);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into moneytest values ('100.00');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type money: "100.00"
СТРОКА 1: insert into moneytest values ('100.00');
                                        ^
melkij=> insert into moneytest values ('100,00');
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> set lc_monetary to 'C';
SET
melkij=> insert into moneytest values ('100.00');
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> insert into moneytest values ('100,00');
INSERT 0 1
melkij=> table moneytest ;
     v      
------------
    $100.00
    $100.00
 $10,000.00
melkij=> reset lc_monetary ;
RESET
melkij=> table moneytest ;
      v      
-------------
    100,00 ₽
    100,00 ₽
 10 000,00 ₽
```

Заметили как мило $10000 превратились в 10000 рублей? Классный обменный курс. Самое печальное, что при запросах с приложения этот символ валюты вместе с другим форматированием так на приложение и идёт.

Это можно обойти приводя `money` к `numeric`, но зачем, если можно использовать напрямую `numeric`?

В общем тип данных есть, задумка наверное неплохая, но вот в реальности им пользоваться неудобно.

PS: кстати любопытная деталь реализации - `money` это не подвид `numeric`, а вариация 64-битного целого `bigint`. Только выводится со смещением в два десятичных знака.

Comment: Спасибо уже какой раз выручаете, столько типов и не понятно что нужно на практике использовать, а то читаю документацию, вижу money, а потом оказывается что с ним проблематично работать.

Comment: только в базовом виде есть за 200 базовых типов данных, не считая расширений и возможностей добавления собственных типов. Среди них ожидаемо бывает что-то не вполне удобное или странное

Comment: Походу в следующем вопросе я постараюсь судя из своего маленького опыта описать частоиспользующие типы данных в Postgresql, жду ваших поправок :)

Comment: сомневаюсь что это получится хороший вопрос с точки зрения правил SO. Частоиспользуемые типы - нет объективного ответа.

Comment: Ну вкратце же можно описать частоиспользующиеся типы данных - строки (varchar, text), целые числа (int, bigint, smallint), для денег (numeric или decimal, чтобы получить точность вычислений потому, что money сам по себе проблематичный как вы сказали), дата (date и timestamp). Вроде из основных всё, поправьте если не так сказал.